# Allow touchmove for child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to disable scrolling for my entire jqm web app but if you try to scroll on a div with a certain class, then scrolling is allowed

So my scrolling div, `.info` has `overflow:scroll` applied to it and I have this script to try to detect if you're touching it

```
$('.info').bind('touchstart', function (e) {
    if (e.type == "touchstart") {
       return true; 
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
$(document).bind('touchmove', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Right now, scrolling is turned off for the document but when I try to scroll my info div, it won't scroll.

Now I've seen a few post around this same idea, but mostly about to pinning an objects position so that when the document is scrolled, it stays in the same place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I've been doing it:

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(ev) {
 if ( !$(ev.target).closest('.is-scrollable').length ) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Where `.is-scrollable` would be your class, `.info` in this case.

EDIT: to fix scrolling at top and bottom of scrollable div:

```
$('.is-scrollable').on('touchstart', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if ( el.scrollTop() <= 0 ) {
      el.scrollTop(1);
    }
    if ( el.scrollTop() >= el[0].scrollHeight ) {
      el.scrollTop(el[0].scrollHeight - 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: This fails at the edges of the container. For example, if you scroll to the end of the `is-scrollable` container and then start a new scroll and continue to scroll down, it will move the background page.

Comment: That's true. You'll also need to incorporate something like my edit adds. It'd be nice if there was a way around that besides this though.